# Magento - How to create attribute programmatically that can be used in 'Sort by'

Tags: magento, sorting, attributes, product

I need to programmatically create several attributes.

Here is a part of my upgrade script  :

```
$dataOrder = array(
    'attribute_set'           => 'Main',
    'group'                   => 'Datawarehouse',
    'type'                    => 'int',
    'input'                   => 'text',
    'label'                   => 'Total order quantity',
    'global'                  => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
    'required'                => 0,
    'comparable'              => 0,
    'searchable'              => 0,
    'unique'                  => 0,
    'user_defined'            => 1,
    'visible_on_front'        => 1,
    'visible'                 => 1,
    'is_filterable'           => 1,
    'used_for_sort_by'        => 1,
    'used_in_product_listing' => 1,
);
```

My script works fine, all my attributes are created but I can't see them in the `Sort by` dropdown (frontend). In back office I can see my attributes, I can assign a value, all good.

But under `Catalog -> Manage Attributes -> Properties -> Frontend properties` : Used for Sorting in Product Listing is set to 'No'.

I thought that `used_for_sort_by` and `used_in_product_listing` would be enough but looks like it's not.

How can I set it to yes, without having to change it in the back office? Either by adding some lines in my upgrade script or by adding some code somewhere else.

**EDIT** I just realized that it's not only Used for Sorting in Product Listing that is not updating the right way. Everything below `required` isn't updating the way it should be, everything is set to 'No'.

Comment: May be it can help you: https://gist.github.com/antoinekociuba/0a4e371509879103b8dd

Comment: I still have the same issue.

Comment: Do you have the same  issue even if you reindex attributes after create this new one?

Comment: Yes I do. I can see in table `catalog_eav_attribute` that `used_for_sort_by` is still set to 0 instead of 1.

I could do a query to set it to 1 but I don't think it's a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you are calling addAttribute() method on a deprecated class. Try:

```
$installer = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/setup', 'catalog_setup');
$installer->addAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, 'attribute_id', $dataOrder);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is will work fine. `'used_for_sort_by' => true` should work.

```
$eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'sell_counts',
            [
                'type' => 'text',
                'backend' => '',
                'frontend' => '',
                'label' => 'Sell Count',
                'input' => 'text',
                'class' => '',
                'source' => '',
                'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                'visible' => true,
                'required' => false,
                'user_defined' => false,
                'default' => '',
                'searchable' => true,
                'filterable' => true,
                'comparable' => true,
                'visible_on_front' => true,
                'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                'used_for_sort_by' => true,
                'unique' => false,
                'apply_to' => ''
            ]
        );
```